# flutter WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://api.****.com/?token=*****#' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: flutter, api, dart, websocket, postman

So guys i am trying to connect to an websocket in order to get some data streams. However, the connection can not be established with my link but it does work with some test links such as `"wss://ws.ifelse.io/"`.

I use `web_socket_channel: ^2.2.0` package

My code is simple;

```
  WebSocketChannel channel2 = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      'wss://api.***.com?token=***');

  void getDataFromApi() {
    channel2.stream.listen((event) {
      if (event != null) {
        print("event");
        print(event);
      }
    });
  }
```

then i call this method in a page's initState but it throws an error;

```
E/flutter (11293): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: 
WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketChannelException: WebSocketException: Connection to 
'https://api.***.com:0?token=***#' was not upgraded to websocket
E/flutter (11293): #0      new IOWebSocketChannel._withoutSocket.<anonymous closure> (package:web_socket_channel/io.dart:98:24)
E/flutter (11293): #1      _invokeErrorHandler (dart:async/async_error.dart:45:24)
E/flutter (11293): #2      _HandleErrorStream._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:269:9)
E/flutter (11293): #3      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleError (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:157:13)
E/flutter (11293): #4      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
E/flutter (11293): #5      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
E/flutter (11293): #6      _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1252:7)
E/flutter (11293): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
E/flutter (11293): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:7)
E/flutter (11293): #9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter (11293): #10     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:778:19)
E/flutter (11293): #11     _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:656:7)
E/flutter (11293): #12     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
E/flutter (11293): #13     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
E/flutter (11293): #14     _CustomZone.runBinaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1252:7)
E/flutter (11293): #15     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError.sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:360:15)
E/flutter (11293): #16     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:378:7)
E/flutter (11293): #17     _BufferingStreamSubscription._addError (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:280:7)
E/flutter (11293): #18     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:778:19)
E/flutter (11293): #19     _StreamController._addError (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:656:7)
E/flutter (11293): #20     new Stream.fromFuture.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:251:18)
E/flutter (11293): #21     _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1450:47)
E/flutter (11293): #22     _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1342:19)
E/flutter (11293): #23     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter (11293): #24     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter (11293): #25     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter (11293): #26     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
E/flutter (11293): #27     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665:7)
E/flutter (11293): #28     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter (11293): #29     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (11293): #30     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (11293): #31     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (11293): #32     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (11293): #33     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter (11293):
```

This api link works in postman as well but i couldn't manage to run this in flutter.

I would be very grateful for any suggestions in order to resolve this issue.

**Edit:**

When i use `socket_io_client: ^2.0.0` package, I managed to connect and get data from the api.

Comment: `Uri.parse('wss://api.***.com?token=***')`, does it make any difference?

Comment: @Denzel no, it does not.